# Spring data - @TextIndexed - exclude property

Tags: search, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following Document in my Spring Data/MongoDB application

```
@Document
public class DocumentFile {

    @Id
    private String id;
    @TextIndexed
    private List<DocumentFileVersion> documentFileVersions;

    ...
}
```

There is a reference to do `DocumentFileVersion`. This class looks like this:

```
public class DocumentFileVersion {

    private String filePath; // contains project name
    ...
}
```

The `DocumentFile`s are included in a Project.
My problem now is that if I search for a project name also the `DocumentFile`s are found because they have the project name included in the field `DocumentFile#DocumentFileVersions#filePath`

My question now would be if there is a possibility to exclude the field `filePath` from `@TextIndexed`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `DocumentFileVersion` is under your control, then you could be adding `@TextIndexed` to only those properties in `DocumentFileVersion` that you want to have indexed simply leaving out `filePath`.

Another approach would be to set up the index manually via `IndexOperations`. Maybe you want to have a look at the [examples project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/mongodb/text-search).